# how to make django model atomicity rollback upon 4xx or 5xx HTTP status codes

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, transactions

I understand that, django atomicity out-of-the-box rolls back a transaction only when an exception is thrown out. But, there are several exceptions that i am catching in my script and for those exceptions i am producing a nice HTTPresponse with some meaningful response content for the user - but i am always making sure that the HTTPresponse upon such cases are sent out with proper 4xx or 5xx HTTP status codes. When such an HTTPresponse happens, i want django to rollback all db queries it might performed till now. But, django atomicity doesn't seem to act based on the HTTP status code that is being sent out, it acts only based on the Exception that is thrown to the user. Any suggestions how i could solve this in `django 1.8` on `python 2.7`?

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a custom middleware that will do this. Here's an example of one [based on the old `TransactionMiddleware`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/_modules/django/middleware/transaction/) (this is untested):

```
from django.db import transaction

class StatusCodeTransactionMiddleware(object):
    """
    Rolls back the current transaction for all responses with 4xx or 5xx status
    codes.
    """

    def process_request(self, request):
        """Enters transaction management"""
        transaction.enter_transaction_management()

    def process_response(self, request, response):
        """Commits and leaves transaction management."""
        if response.status_code >= 400:
            if transaction.is_dirty():
                # This rollback might fail because of network failure for
                # example. If rollback isn't possible it is impossible to
                # clean the connection's state. So leave the connection in
                # dirty state and let request_finished signal deal with
                # cleaning the connection.
                transaction.rollback()
            transaction.leave_transaction_management()
        else:
            if not transaction.get_autocommit():
                if transaction.is_dirty():
                    # Note: it is possible that the commit fails. If the
                    # reason is closed connection or some similar reason,
                    # then there is little hope to proceed nicely.
                    # However, in some cases ( deferred foreign key checks
                    # for example) it is still possible to rollback().
                    try:
                        transaction.commit()
                    except Exception:
                        # If the rollback fails, the transaction state will
                        # be messed up. It doesn't matter, the connection
                        # will be set to clean state after the request
                        # finishes. And, we can't clean the state here
                        # properly even if we wanted to, the connection is
                        # in transaction but we can't rollback...
                        transaction.rollback()
                        transaction.leave_transaction_management()
                        raise
                transaction.leave_transaction_management()
        return response
```

Put this in your `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` like so:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    "myapp.middleware.StatusCodeTransactionMiddleware",
    # Other middleware...
)
```

Comment: looks great... i will try this and update accordingly

Comment: btw @grantmcconnaughey, enter_transaction_management() is trans start and leave_transaction_management() is COMMIT?

Comment: I also have "ATOMIC_REQUEST" set to TRUE. Will that interfere?

Comment: Done. It now commits. Again, this is all just taken from the old `TransactionMiddleware` class and it hasn't been tested. I don't think I would use `ATOMIC_REQUESTS` with this as it pretty much does the same thing, but I don't think it would hurt. You could even update this middleware to rollback the transaction on an exception as well, which means it would handle both status codes >= 400 and exceptions during the request/response cycle. If you do that then I would definitely set `ATOMIC_REQUESTS` to `False`.

Comment: just created a middleware and added it into `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = {"contactapp.middleware.RequestResponseTransaction"}`. Getting the following error when accessing a page. `ImportError: Module "myapp.middleware.RequestResponseTransaction" does not define a "RequestResponseTransaction" attribute/class` The middleware has been saved in `djangoproject/myapp/middleware/RequestResponseTransaction.py`

Comment: It needs to be stored in middleware.py, not RequestResponseTransaction.py. RequestResponseTransaction is the name of the class and middleware is the of the module it is in. Look at other examples of Django MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES to see what I mean.

Comment: in [django1.8 doc for transactions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/transactions/#transactions) it says "Django doesn’t provide an API to start a transaction. The expected way to start a transaction is to disable autocommit with set_autocommit().". So in middleware's `process_request()` i do `transaction.set_autocommit(False)` and in middleware's `process_response()` i do `transaction.rollback()`. Nothing else are in there right now. I get an error "The outermost 'atomic' block cannot use savepoint = False when autocommit is off." whereas i never configured any savepoint anywer